# Pulsating border on button

Tags: css, button

I've been tooling around with a button that I want on my website but I've ran into a problem. My website uses forced scrolling (like on Apple's iPhone 5S page) and everytime I scroll up or down my button get's screwed.. :(

It seems like the purple pulsating one gets placed on top of the other's for no apparent reason! It's really annoying me and I can't seem to find the answer... :(

Here's a demo of the button:

```
<div class="button">
    <div class="blackspace"></div>
    <div class="blueunderlay"></div>
    <div class="roundbutton"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.roundbutton {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 77px;
    height: 77px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation-name: fadecolor;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    z-index: 2;
    top: -152px;
}
.blueunderlay {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 77px;
    height: 77px;
    position: relative;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#01BAE8), to(#0183D5));
    top: -75px;
}
.blackspace {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 73px;
    height: 73px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 4;
    left: 2px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadecolor {
    from {
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#EB009F), to(#DA005B))
    }
    40% {
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#EB009F), to(#DA005B));
        opacity: 0.25
    }
    50% {
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#EB009F), to(#DA005B));
        opacity: 0
    }
    60% {
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#EB009F), to(#DA005B));
        opacity: 0.25
    }
    to {
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#EB009F), to(#DA005B))
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6P3F7/2/

I hope someone will be able to help me out :)

Comment: That seems like a lot of HTML to create what is a pretty simple effect. You have 4 elements where, probably, you only need one..unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Probably... I did not say it was efficient :P Feel free to create a simpler one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could manage this with a single element and a pseudo-element which should solve the positioning issues.

[**Codepen.io Demo**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/mBghC)

**HTML**

```
<div class="newbutton"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.newbutton {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 73px;
  height: 73px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: black;
  margin: 25px;
}

.newbutton:before {
  content:"";
  width:80px;
  height:80px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius:50%;
  z-index:-1;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  -webkit-animation-name: fadecolor;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadecolor {
  from {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#EB009F), to(#DA005B))
  }
  40% {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#EB009F), to(#DA005B));
    opacity: 0.25
  }
  50% {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#EB009F), to(#DA005B));
    opacity: 0
  }
  60% {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#EB009F), to(#DA005B));
    opacity: 0.25
  }
  to {
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#EB009F), to(#DA005B))
  }
}
```

NOTE: Only using -webkit prefixes and copied gradient at present...but it's pretty much there, I think.